# Как закрыть не зарегистрированному пользователю страницу?

Tags: php

Как закрыть не зарегистрированному пользователю страницу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правило, информация об авторизированном пользователе хранится в сессии, таким образом после авторизации пользователя задаем `$_SESSION['auth'] = true;` затем каждый раз делаем проверку:

```
if($_SESSION['auth']){
//показываем страницу
}else{
//делаем что нить еще, например, выводим форму авторизации
}
```